# Notify and Write characteristic to differents characteristic consecutively

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to receive notifications in a characteristic and then write text in another characteristic of the same BLE device. But when writing to the device most of the time it disconnects me, because something will not go well I imagine. This is the code.

```
BluetoothGatt gatt = null;
    BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                gatt.close();
            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = null;

        if (BLOODGLUCOSE_MODEL.equals(GlobalNames.ADF_B27)) {
            characteristic = gatt.getService(BLOODGLUCOSE_SERVICEUDID).getCharacteristic(BLOODGLUCOSE_NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTICSUDID);
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = null;

        try {
            if (BLOODGLUCOSE_MODEL.equals(GlobalNames.ADF_B27)) {
                characteristic =
                        gatt.getService(BLOODGLUCOSE_SERVICEUDID)
                                .getCharacteristic(BLOODGLUCOSE_WRITE_CHARACTERISTICSUDID);
                byte[] byteValue = new byte[10];
                byteValue[0] = (byte)0x5A;
                byteValue[1] = (byte)0x0A;
                byteValue[2] = (byte)0x00;
                byteValue[3] = (byte)0x14;
                byteValue[4] = (byte)0x09;
                byteValue[5] = (byte)0x14;
                byteValue[6] = (byte)0x0A;
                byteValue[7] = (byte)0x05;
                byteValue[8] = (byte)0x09;
                byteValue[9] = (byte)0xAF;
                characteristic.setValue(byteValue);
                (gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {  }
    }
}
```

I  can see that writeDescriptor() and writeCharacteristic always returns true.
Does anyone see any errors?

Thanks.

Comment: No your code cannot cause a disconnection. It must be some other reason for disconnection. What's the "status" parameter at the disconnection?

Comment: @Emil status at the disconnection is 8

Comment: That means Connection Timeout, which is an issue on the radio level (happens for example when the signal is too weak) and has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @Emil Debugging I'm seeing that if i put a breakpoint in gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic) and I wait 2-3 seconds it works. I don't know the reason.